# How to rewrite from sub URL to sub directory with htaccess?

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess

My backend is PHP and in the frontend I want to have a reactJS compiled project that I want to allow user access to via `example.com/app` and that compiled project's `index.html` file is placed in `/var/www/html/reactjs/build/index.html` and I need to somehow rewrite all `example.com/app` requests to that directory otherwise the reactJS app won't work properly / at all.

This is what I've tried to do and not working for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/app /reactjs/build/index.html [QSA,L]
```

IDK what else to try, I'd love to get a direction on how to solve this issue :)

Comment: The question is: where is your application logic? A html file ("index.html") is a _passive_ file that does not execute any logic.

Comment: @arkascha I wrote in the post the directory of the react's index.html file, it points to all the needed JS files which then on the frontend handle all the routing with react-router
All I'm trying to do is make example.com/app and example.com/app/whatever rewrite to react's index.html file which lies in this directory /html/reactjs/build/index.html

Comment: I doubt that's gonna work. If you rewrite _all_ requests to the file then only that file will get delivered, again and again. That certainly is _not_ what you want! You also want to deliver the JS files and whatever.

Comment: @arkascha Gotcha so instead of the file the directory.. do you know haw can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/app /reactjs/build/index.html [QSA,L]
> ```

In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so this would need to be rewritten:

```
RewriteRule ^app /reactjs/build/index.html [L]
```

The `QSA` flag is also not required here.

> **UPDATE:** site I'm using is a wordpress site

These directives need to go *before* the WordPress front-controller, otherwise these requests for `/app/...` will be routed to WordPress instead. For example:

```
# ReactJS routing...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^app /reactjs/build/index.html [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/
I'm getting a 404 error when I try to go to exmaple.com/app

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? (This is to be used with the `RewriteCond` directive you had originally.)

Comment: Yes, the site I'm using is a wordpress site, here's the full htaccess file: https://pastebin.com/cDsFp9fw

Comment: These directives need to go _before_ the WordPress front-controller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK now it kind of working, just last few things:
1. When I load the page I can see that it tries to load the css and js files but instead it gets the index.html file and therefore nothing is rendered and I only see a white blank page. and I tried to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` so it won't rewrite directories if they exist but it still loads the index.html instead of the css and js files..
2. when I go to example.com/app (w/o the / at the end) it tries to grab the css and js files root instead of trying from the current dir but when I add the / it tries to load the right files

Comment: 1. What is the URL-path to your CSS and JS files in the HTML source. What is the intended filesystem path of your CSS and JS files? 2. It sounds like you are specifying a relative path to your CSS and JS files. The browser/client sees `/app` (without a trailing slash) as a file in the root directory, whereas `/app/` is a "directory" - any relative client-side URL to a resource is relative to this URL.

Comment: These files were automatically generated by react when I compiled my project. In the same folder as react's index.html I have a folder called "static" and in that folder there's a "css" folder, "js" folder and "media" folder and inside each of them is their respective files (in "media" is all the images)... So if let's say you wanna access one of the css files you need to go to /www/html/reactjs/build/static/css/whatever.css